# Where are my ko.observable properties?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am *trying* to output to the dom data-bind="text: row.state()" and it *does not work*. I don't believe the issue is with json.stringify, it is there just as an example of the fact that the values are not visible to the `ko foreach` in the html

http://jsfiddle.net/bkj37mzu/11/

```
thing = {
            id: 3,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        }
```

I'm in the middle of trying to debug something in a much larger app, and I'm trying to make a simple example of how my app is breaking, and I can't even get my basic objects properties to show up.

Where are my 2 ko.observable properites on each thing object in rows? When I try to use "row.state()" it isn't there, it doesn't exist, as you can see in the stringified "text" in the dom.

Thoughts please.

Comment: I'm confused - The JSFiddle doesn't have any observable properties (expect the array)

Comment: oops forgot to update, check it now

Comment: You looked at the console right? At the error : `SyntaxError: missing } after property list`. Here i fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/bkj37mzu/8/

Comment: ok, now please check again. it isn't the syntax error, I was trying something else, and forgot to put everything back in its place. You will see that I am stringifying my rows and they print out only the ID property of each thing. But there are 3 properties, and 2 of them (the ko observables) are not visible...............

Comment: I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: If you updated it in jsfiddle the URL changed - you still have the original in the question

Comment: hey guys, sorry, I'm new to fiddle. check again please

Comment: There are many other problems with the fiddle. For instance, the observable properties aren't being set properly. `row.bool = !row.bool` should be `row.bool(!row.bool())`.

Comment: Does my answer not show exactly how to output your `state` property to the DOM.

Answer (score 4):

The observables are there - it's just that you're using JSON.stringfy on the objects that contain them. This will exclude functions and only serialize POJO's (Plain Old JavaScript Objects).

As Jamiec points out, each of the observables are actually functions, so their content doesn't get serialized.

So for each of your boxes you serialize:

```
  thing = {
        id: 1,
        bool: ko.observable(false),
        state: ko.observable('disabled')
    },
    thing = {
        id: 2,
        bool: ko.observable(false),
        state: ko.observable('disabled')
    },
    thing = {
        id: 3,
        bool: ko.observable(false),
        state: ko.observable('disabled')
    }
```

The only possible output of that, is the 3 ID's.

If you convert your object to a normal JavaScript object, so that these properties are no longer functions, then it will serialize as you expect:

```js
var viewModel = {
 
    toggle: function (row) {
        row.bool(!row.bool);
    },
    displayState: function(row){
        
      if(row.bool()){
            row.state('enabled');
        }   else{
            row.state('disabled');
        }
        console.log(row.state);
    },
    rows: [
        thing = {
            id: 1,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        },
        thing = {
            id: 2,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        },
        thing = {
            id: 3,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        },
    ],

    tabs: [
        tab = 'tab1',
        tab ='tab2',
        tab = 'tab3'

    ],
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!--ko foreach: {data: tabs, as: 'tab'} -->

<div class="nav nav-tabs">
    <p>This is <span data-bind='text: tab'></span>
    </p>
</div>
    <!--ko foreach: {data: $root.rows, as: 'row'}-->
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($root.rows)), click: function(){$root.toggle(row)}"></button>
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Just to note that the observables are perfectly visible in the `foreach` as the following snippet shows. As we've discussed, the reason you can't see them is because of the serialization. This example shows how to consume them just by displaying a paragraph element:

```js
var viewModel = {
 
    toggle: function (row) {
        row.bool(!row.bool);
    },
    displayState: function(row){
        
      if(row.bool()){
            row.state('enabled');
        }   else{
            row.state('disabled');
        }
        console.log(row.state);
    },
    rows: [
        thing = {
            id: 1,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('enabled')
        },
        thing = {
            id: 2,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        },
        thing = {
            id: 3,
            bool: ko.observable(false),
            state: ko.observable('disabled')
        },
    ],

    tabs: [
        tab = 'tab1',
        tab ='tab2',
        tab = 'tab3'

    ],
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!--ko foreach: {data: tabs, as: 'tab'} -->

<div class="nav nav-tabs">
    <p>This is <span data-bind='text: tab'></span>
    </p>
</div>
    <!--ko foreach: {data: $root.rows }-->
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: id"></button>
<p data-bind="text: state"></p>
    <!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: except when I stringify them in my app, they are there. The functions print out as function(), they at least have the property name there. this is abnormal. Even when I try to access them as "row

Comment: To make it 100% clear, when you write `ko.observable(blah)` you're creating a *function* and `JSON.stringify` excludes them

Comment: I have stringified functions before. I have logged functions before, and it types out "function (){...}" or something to that effect. 

This is NOT normal behavior. When I stringify in my app, the functions properties are still there. When I try to use the "text: row.state()" in the html, it does not work, as if it is not there, or has no value, or is undefined. This is incorrect.

I'm not first day using KO. this is not normal

Comment: Worth noting that simply calling `ko.toJS` and then calling `JSON.stringify` on the result or just calling `ko.toJSON` will do the right thing (see [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bkj37mzu/9/)).

Comment: This behavior is clearly documented here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: @nathanrogers I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j450kjue/) and `JSON.stringify` always ignores functions

Comment: When you access a function via the JavaScript console - then yes it will print the output. This is a browser debugging feature - and you can convert the function code to a string. This is not what JSON.stringify does by default however.

Comment: @nathanrogers Ive flagged your comments w/swearing as rude, they will be gone. Do you want to try again with a civil tongue? People here *are* trying to help you after all!

Comment: @Ian The observables `bool` and `state` are being set incorrectly.

Comment: @CrimsonChris thanks, wasn't really focusing on those but have corrected for completeness

Comment: Thanks, still missing one though. `if (row.bool())`

Comment: @CrimsonChris doh, if you can mind editing? Find it awkward via phone app. If not will fix a little later

Answer (score 1):

The `state` observable absolutely *is* there, its just the way you're outputting the data hides them

You can see this by updating the binding on your buttons:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="text: row.state, click: function(){$root.toggle(row)}"></button>
-------------------------------------------------^ here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkj37mzu/12/

---

You should also be aware that when you get or set the value of an observable you do so like you're calling a function, so

```
row.bool = !row.bool;
```

should be

```
row.bool(!row.bool())
```

(H/T: @CrimsonChris )

The same goes for some of the way you're setting `state`. In all, with all the problems fixed I think this fiddle does what you were trying to do in the first place

http://jsfiddle.net/bkj37mzu/21/